# Change ngFor list thru dropdown menu via filter pipe in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

how can I acomplish to change the view of my list when i select one option on dropdown list, via filter pipe? users I get from service... list is functioning, but it would be nice if I could filter it since it has hundreds of users active and inactive...

in app.component.ts

```
inactiveUser: string = 'All';
```

in my app.component.html i have ngFor that shows me all users

```
     <tr *ngFor="let user of userlist">
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
     </tr>
```

above, I've created simple dropwdown

```
    <select id="ActiveUser" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="inactiveUser">
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="Active">Active</option>
            <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
        </select>
```

Inactive users have prefix of inactive in their mail, for example inactive_john.doe@gmail.com, so I'm trying to filter those with that prefix, but don't know how...

I've created pipe using cli

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

 @Pipe({
  name: 'inactiveUsers'
 })
 export class InactiveUsersPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: string, args: any[]): string | boolean {

      //example
      //var str = "inactive_john.doe@mail.com";
      //var n = str.includes("inactive");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the pipe in your template.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let user of (userlist | inactiveUsers: inactiveUser)">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
 </tr>
```

The `value` passed to your `transform` function in the pipe will be the `userlist`, so you need to filter on that and return.

```
transform(userlist: { email: string }[], filter: string): { email: string }[] {

      switch (filter): {

      case 'All': return userlist;

      case 'Active': return userlist.filter((user: { email: string }) => {
           return user.email.indexOf('inactive_') === -1;
      });

      case 'Inactive': return userlist.filter((user: { email: string }) => {
           return user.email.indexOf('inactive_') !== -1;
      });
}
```

The above will take the filter value passed to the pipe from `inactiveUsers: inactiveUser` from your select `ngModel` and determine what way to filter the results.

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/euV5s6

Comment: when I select something from dropdown, I get back Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: when All is selected, there are no errors, something is wrong with includes function I guess

Comment: Edited, `includes` is on arrays, not strings. :facepalm:

Comment: you're the best :D

Answer (score 0):

You could do `pipe`, or just simply another function call. The following example assumes you need to filter by matching a string

```
private filterItems(val) {
    if (val) {
        ... do your filtering
    } else {
        this.filteredItems = this.items.slice(0);
    }
}
```

And then call this function when you want it, ex.

```
onFilterChange(val) {
    this.filterItems(val);
}
```

and in template

```
(ngModelChange)="onFilterChange($event)"
```

I found this is more flexible and efficient in most of cases.